# Wait for the Appearance of the second text in an element that contains same text values in Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-android

Just say there are two texts named "output",
the first text "output" shows up in a textfield, but now I want to wait till the second text "output" shows up in the textfield.

I tried this,

```
WebdriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedCondition.text_to_be_present((By.ID,":id/tvResult"),"output",2))
```

Comment: Why not visibility for second `output` element ?

Comment: @cruisepandey the text "output" is in the same element I just have to wait till the second output shows up? i am getting solution for it